# Verify my answer: Show that the nullspace of $Ax=0$ is a subspace of the reals

Tags: linear-algebra

1.It contains the zero vector because $A0=0$
2. It is closed under addition ie $(Ax+Ay)$=$A(x+y)$=$0$
3. It is closed under scalar multiplication $(kA)x=k(Ax)=k0=0$

So it is a subspace

Comment: its not right. you should vary x not A. null space of A is a collection of all vectors x such that Ax=0

Comment: This is a sloppy question. What is fixed and what varies in $Ax=0$?

Answer (score 3):

Number 1. is okay. Numbers 2 and 3 not.

To show it is closed under vector addition, assume $x, y \in N(A)$ and show that $x+y$ is also in $N(A)$, which means you need to show that $A(x+y) = 0$.

To show that it is closed under scalar multiplication, let $k$ be any scalar and $x\in N(A)$. You need to show that $kx \in N(A)$ i.e. you need to show that $A(kx) = 0$.

In both cases use the linearity properties of $A$.

Comment: I have made some edits

Comment: Both are still incorrect. What is this $B$ anyway?

Comment: Edited again and I hope this time I used the right notation. So x is the thing that varies so y is another vector in this subspace.

Comment: Number 2 is getting closer. Technically you should swap the order of your first two equalities - i.e. write $A(x + y) = Ax + Ay = 0 + 0 = 0$. This would be axiomatically correct. Similarly for #3 you want $A(kx) = kAx = k0 = 0$. Each equality is justified via the linearity of $A$ or a vector space axiom.